# How to set initial basemap in web appbuilter developer edition?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I wan to set a basemap in my basemap gallery. This is my web appbuilder developer edition configuration file.

```
{
  "theme": {
    "name": "LaunchpadTheme",
    "styles": ["default", "style2", "style3"],
    "version": "2.4"
  },
  "portalUrl": "https://arcgis.swissmediacast.ch/portal",
  "appId": "",
  "authorizedCrossOriginDomains": ["geodata.state.nj.us", "ahocevar.com", "wms.geo.admin.ch"],
  "title": "Wallis",
  "subtitle": "",
  "keepAppState": true,
  "logo": "",
  "geometryService": "https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer",
  "links": [],
  "map": {
    "3D": false,
    "2D": true,
    "position": {
      "left": 0,
      "top": 0,
      "right": 0,
      "bottom": 0
    },
    "itemId": "3f2202ad86704ca595280484910dfb2d",
    "mapOptions": {
      "extent": {
        "xmin": 2491135.701601292,
        "ymin": 1060085.625618667,
        "xmax": 2755886.37406769,
        "ymax": 1269336.157114772,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 2056
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "map",
    "portalUrl": "https://arcgis.swissmediacast.ch/portal/"
  }
}
```

And I have a basemap config json.

```
{
  "basemapGallery": {
    "showArcGISBasemaps": false,
    "mode": 0,
    "basemaps": [      
      {
        "title": "my map",
        "thumbnailUrl": "images/img.png",
        "layers": [
            {
                "url": "...",
                "id": "m1",
                "type": "WebTiledLayer",
             }
         ]
      }
     ]
   }
}
```

So I want to start application using m1 basemap.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial basemap is defined in the web map item, not the web app. Simply open the webmap in your Portal and change to the `m1` basemap, then save.

Comment: But m1 is not defined in portal, I defined it in code bese of web appbuilder. How can I cahnge it?